# not able to run rails server its giving issue Could not find minitest-5.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Hi am not able to run rails server its giving issue `Could not find minitest-5.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` and when I do bundle install it does not show any error my gemfile is as given:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Please help me out in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a try: `gem install minitest` and `bundle install`

Comment: It could be a dependency of some other gem in your gemfile I believe. So if you can comment out each of the specified gems and test, you can find out the culprit.

Comment: I had just simply solve it out by just creating new gemset and use it and after that done bundle install and it works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be due to your global Rails installation (or ruby for that matter) being a different version than the rails version you're trying to run for your project (4.2.1).

Are you using `bundle exec` before your `rails s` command to ensure you're using the gems specified in your `Gemfile`?